# Iterating over array with Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, nashorn

When using java's built-in javascript interpreter, why can I iterate over a java List using Arrays.forEach() but not over a native array? I have the following test code

```
var ArrayList = Java.type('java.util.ArrayList');
var list = new ArrayList();
list.add('a');
list.add('b');
list.add('c');

var StringArray = Java.type("java.lang.String[]");
var array = new StringArray(3);
array[0] = "A";
array[1] = "B";
array[2] = "C";

list.forEach(function(v) { print(v); });
array.forEach(function(v) { print(v); });
```

which I'd expect to print out

> a b c A B C

but instead I get

> a b c
>
> TypeError: [Ljava.lang.String;@644e4fbf has no such function "forEach" in  at line number 14

The following works, but why not array.forEach() ?

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; ++i)
  print(array[i]);
```

The issue I have is that my javascript code wants to call a load of java functions that return a String[], and I want to deal with the resulting object as if was a regular javascript array. Is there an easier way to fix this than writing loads of wrapper functions in java that convert my arrays to an ArrayList?

Comment: You can use the (extremely unfortunate, in my opinion) Nashorn `for each (var element in array)` syntax. (Taken from Mozilla extensions that have, I think, been quashed in modern Firefox.)

Answer (score 7):

When you call forEach on a Java List, you are invoking the List's forEach method inherited from [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-). Nashorn supports passing a script function whenever a `@FunctionalInterface` object is expected and so you can pass function as argument for the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) parameter. There is no such forEach Java method on Java arrays and hence the second forEach method call fails.

Note that the Nashorn implementation of the JavaScript Array.prototype.[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is generic. It works on Java arrays, lists as well. I adjusted your script to use Array.prototype.forEach for both Java List and java String array.

```
var ArrayList = Java.type('java.util.ArrayList');
var list = new ArrayList();
list.add('a');
list.add('b');
list.add('c');

var StringArray = Java.type("java.lang.String[]");
var array = new StringArray(3);
array[0] = "A";
array[1] = "B";
array[2] = "C";

var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

forEach.call(list, function(v) { print(v); });
forEach.call(array, function(v) { print(v); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. It's not just about iterating over the array but also that people writing scripts might expect to call functions like Arrays.sort(), Arrays.filter() etc.

In the end I decided to change all the Java functions so they return a true JavaScript array, rather than a native Java array, by passing them through a helper function to call Java.from():

```
private JSObject toJavascript(Object javaObject)
{
    String tmpkey = "tmp"+javaObject.hashCode()+System.currentTimeMillis();
    engine.put(tmpkey, javaObject);
    JSObject jsObject = (JSObject)engine.eval("Java.from("+tmpkey+")");
    engine.put(tmpkey, null);
    return jsObject;
}
```

There's probably a neater to do this but at least it seems to work!